# How to get back a missing Network menu in Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: network-manager, panel

I am using Ubuntu14.04. Network menu in my Panel has disappeared. How do I get this network item back?

Results of running `nm-applet`

```
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

(nm-applet:3516): nm-applet-WARNING **: Could not find ShellVersion property on org.gnome.Shell after 5 tries
^Cnm-applet-Message: PID 0 (we are 3516) sent signal 2, shutting down...

(nm-applet:3516): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 101 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

Results of running `killall nm-applet && setsid nm-applet`

```
nm-applet-Message: 
using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon (nm-applet:3647): 
nm-applet-WARNING **: Could not find ShellVersion property on org.gnome.Shell

Results of running `setsid compiz --replace && setsid unity`

ERROR 2014-09-03 08:55:06 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'

ERROR 2014-09-03 08:55:06 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'
```

please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: Install a gksu package using terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Step2: Open `Alt+F2` and type `gksu`. Then,click on gksu icon to open it.

Step3: Type `nm-applet` in a run command.

Step4: Restart your system.

Now, disappeared network  menu will be reappear.