# Ubuntu-GNOME - nm-applet icon just disappears when usb-tethering is active

Tags: unity, gnome, network-manager, icons, ubuntu-gnome

I don't actually use `UbuntuGNOME` distro, but rather installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package on the stock unity-based version of trusty. All other things are smooth after transition, except this one glitch. As soon as I connect my smart-phone and start USB tethering, the `nm-applet` icon in tray just disappears. Once I disconnect, however, the icon appears back. See this:

[image]

The connection happens smoothly despite the lack of tray icon. `ifconfig` returns the proper output.

**EDIT**

`nm-applet` output:

```
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

** (nm-applet:21185): WARNING **: Could not create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/0: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist

^Cnm-applet-Message: PID 0 (we are 21185) sent signal 2, shutting down...
```

**EDIT 2**

Relevant [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761027) I've created on gnome bugzilla.

Comment: Run `nm-applet` from terminal, and check for errors in the output. And peek also at the `~/.xsession-errors` file.

Comment: @Hi-Angel `nm-applet` says this when I start it: `nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon`. Then doesn't do anything as I connect/disconnect tethering. There are also no additions to `~/.xsession-errors` during this time.

Comment: Try running then `nm-applet --shell-debug`, perhaps it would show anything related.

Comment: @Hi-Angel It didn't write anything earlier, but now when I went back to the terminal, it had logged something and I've added it to my question. Does that mean something? (Especially `using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon` ?)

Comment: @Hi-Angel I also tried the workarounds mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/519056/how-to-get-back-a-missing-network-menu-in-ubuntu14-04) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/507310/network-manager-icon-disappeared-14-04), but still could not resolve this.

Comment: Weird. I don't know then. Since there's no errors, I suspect the problem might be either that icon becomes transparent, or perhaps it's a glitch in the panel — then I don't know where its logs, and even what's its executable.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I just found a twist in the behavior. The icon only initially stays invisible when I switch on tethering from my smart-phone and the connection establishes. However, once I disconnect and re-connect the `USB Ethernet` from the main menu on the top-right, the icon appears again. Maybe I have to set some "active" flag in the `dconf` settings?